# Snap vivictpp, no video output, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: video, snap

Use : Ubuntu 20.04, snap vivictpp installed via "Ubuntu Software"

I use the snap to compare locale files, e.g.:
vivictpp "Die Geistervilla.mp4" "Die Geistervilla 22.mp4". The first file is h.262 coded, the second file h.265.
After starting the snap, I will get the info :

"/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids: No such file or directory" and have no video output.

I did check the respective folder, but the file is present.

Now I have no idea, what to do, is there someone who can help.
If additional information will be needed, ask me, I will add it.

Comment: To get more feedback : It is a tool were you can compare two videos (before and after compression), to check the "reduced" quality. Both films will be on screen at a time, and you can compare every part in detail because via mouse you can scroll horizontally frame by frame, via mouse move. The left part of the screen will be the first video, the rest the second, both will be parted by a vertical line.

Comment: Got a working program with some restrictions, please refer to https://github.com/svt/vivictpp/issues/16. It works fine.